# What is the proper usage of the prepositional phrase "of which"?

Tags: possessive-pronouns

Is the second sentence below grammatically correct? If not, why so?

1. We are looking for the house **the windows of which** are broken.
2. We are looking for the house **of which the windows** are broken.

Comment: You may already know this but the next reader of the question might not: more idiomatic than either would be *We are looking for the house with the broken windows.* but it is no more grammatical.

Comment: It's also acceptable to say, *"We are looking for the house whose windows are broken"*.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Both are grammatically correct - and the second more idiomatically usual than the former.

If you want to use the first it might be improved by putting a comma after "house".

Comment: Please provide support for your answer. At present it is an unjustified assertion. The fact that you have a high reputation does not exempt you from the norms of this list. How is the poster or anyone else to know if you are right and, if so, why?